# Why does my wpf vb.net app locks my Access database even after connections are closed?

Tags: .net, vb.net, ms-access

I have a vb.net wpf app running on .net 4.5.2.
This app connects to an Access 2013 database (.accdb) via read and write functions (sort of custom built entity framework with read at the start, write/update/delete at the end).

I have multiple reads and multiple writes successively for each table. They all work without saying that the database is locked.

I create my connectionstring with this function:

```
Function newconnectionstring() As System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnection
    newconnectionstring = New System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnection("myconnectionstring")
End Function
```

These are my last read and write functions:

READ (doesn't seem to keep the database locked)

```
Sub ImportTechnicalLabels()
    TechnicalLabels = New Dictionary(Of String, TechnicalLabel)(StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase)
    Dim accessconnection As System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnection
    accessconnection = newconnectionstring()
    accessconnection.Open()
    Dim sSQL As String = "SELECT * FROM TechnicalLabels"
    Dim objCmd As New OleDbCommand(sSQL, accessconnection)
    Dim reader As OleDbDataReader
    Dim readerTechnicalLabel As TechnicalLabel

    reader = objCmd.ExecuteReader

    While reader.Read
        readerTechnicalLabel = New TechnicalLabel
        With readerTechnicalLabel
            .UpdateStatus = 0
            .TechnicallabelID = reader.Item("TechnicallabelID").ToString
        End With
        TechnicalLabels.Add(readerTechnicalLabel.TechnicalLabelID, readerTechnicalLabel)
    End While

    reader.Close()
    accessconnection.Close()
    accessconnection = Nothing
    reader = Nothing
End Sub
```

WRITE (keep the database locked but allow writes on other tables to proceed)

```
Sub UpdateConcessionlines()
    Dim accessconnection As System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnection
    accessconnection = newconnectionstring()
    accessconnection.Open()
    Dim updatesql As String = "UPDATE Concessionlines SET ConcessionLineID=@ConlID, ConcessionID=@ConID, Defect = @Def, MeasureID=@MeID, Comment =@Com, Numberitembtd  = @Nbibt, LineTechnicalDecisionID = @LTechID WHERE (ConcessionLineID = @ConlID);"
    Dim updatecmd As OleDbCommand
    Dim addsql As String = "INSERT INTO Concessionlines VALUES (@ConlID, @ConID, @Def, @MeID, @Com, @Nbibt, @LTechID);"
    Dim addcmd As OleDbCommand
    Dim deletesql As String = "DELETE FROM Concessionlines WHERE ConcessionLineID = @ConlID"
    Dim deletecmd As OleDbCommand

    For Each item In (From Conlis In Concessionlines.Values Where Conlis.UpdateStatus = 1 Select Conlis).ToList
        updatecmd = New OleDbCommand(updatesql, accessconnection)
        With updatecmd
            If Not item.ConcessionLineID = Nothing Then
                .Parameters.AddWithValue("@ConlID", item.ConcessionLineID)
            Else
                .Parameters.AddWithValue("@ConlID", DBNull.Value)
            End If
            '... and so on
        End With
        updatecmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
    Next item

    For Each item In (From Conlis In Concessionlines.Values Where Conlis.UpdateStatus = 2 Select Conlis).ToList
        addcmd = New OleDbCommand(addsql, accessconnection)
        With addcmd
            If Not item.ConcessionLineID = Nothing Then
                .Parameters.AddWithValue("@ConlID", item.ConcessionLineID)
            Else
                .Parameters.AddWithValue("@ConlID", DBNull.Value)
            End If
            '... and so on
        End With
        addcmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
    Next item

    For Each item In (From Conlis In Concessionlines.Values Where Conlis.UpdateStatus = 3 Select Conlis).ToList
        deletecmd = New OleDbCommand(deletesql, accessconnection)
        With deletecmd
            If Not item.ConcessionLineID = Nothing Then
                .Parameters.AddWithValue("@ConlID", item.ConcessionLineID)
            Else
                .Parameters.AddWithValue("@ConlID", DBNull.Value)
            End If
        End With
        deletecmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
    Next item

    accessconnection.Close()
    accessconnection = Nothing
End Sub
```

But at the end, the database is locked and I cannot launch the entire procedure again.
If I try to manually delete the accdbl file, I have the following message:

> This operation cannot be completed because this file is opened in
>   WpfApplication1.

I have to close my application completely to start again.

Any idea why my access database stays locked?
Or maybe any idea to free the database without knowing what is causing the lock?
Thank you for your help.

**UPDATE**

I've narrowed the problem down.
Apparently the problem comes from the delete operation.
I've organized my code differently by now so i have not solved the issue yet. But what i'm thinking is that the problems may come from the cascade delete option that i chose for some of the access relations. To be verified...

Comment: The error message says it all.You can't really delete a file that's opened in any program. However your post mentions that you can't even delete the file after the connection is closed but your code doesn't seem to show when are you closing the connection. As your code is not arranged,it's hard to determine if the connection is really closed.Why not try **connection.dispose** in a startup task like on a button click, then try to delete the file and see if problem exists

Comment: also try adding **My.Computer.FileSystem.DeleteFile** when you close the connection to delete the file(basically to see if the connection is really closed)

Comment: also try to remove **try-catch** statements to see if the connection closing throws any exceptions